# GLSL rectangle (box) gradient shader

Tags: glsl, gradient

I'm working on gradient shader in GLSL.
I've searched everywhere but didn't have change to find a solution for rectangle gradient that have not "cross" in the middle like this.

[image]

Any suggestions how to overcome this side effect?

Answer (score 0):

In uv coordinate space (0.0, 0.0) to (1.0, 1.0) the important formula are:

- x > y
- -x + 1 > y

These comparisons divide the uv space into four quadrants diagonally

[desmos calculator of these two formula](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/paggpy6qch)

glsl mix function:

```
// return a value `fac` between 0.0 and 1.0
// at uv center (0.5, 0.5) -> 1.0
// at uv edges  (0.0, 0.0) -> 0.0
//              (1.0, 1.0) -> 0.0
float boxmix(vec2 uv) {
    bool ab = (uv.x > uv.y);
    bool cd = (uv.y > -uv.x + 1.);
    
    vec2 duv = uv * 2.;
    float fac = 0.;
    if (ab) {
        if (cd) {
            fac = 2. - duv.x;
        } else {
            fac = duv.y;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (cd) {
            fac = 2. - duv.y;
        } else {
            fac = duv.x;
        }
    }
    return fac;
}
```

example frag color shader:

```
vec3 black = vec3(0.);
vec3 white = vec3(1.);
fragColor = vec4(mix(black, white, boxmix(uv)), 1.);
```

example frag color shader visual:

[image: example frag color shader visual]

---

[desmos calculator visual](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/paggpy6qch)
[image: visual of formula]